# In React Native running ./gradlew assembleRelease product build apk, but the JS code is not updated

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

> In React Native running ./gradlew assembleRelease produce build apk,
> but the JS code is not updated.I also did ./gradlew clean but still no luck.
>
> But If I did below two command the code is updated.
>
> 1. npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-
>    file index.js --bundle-output
>    android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>    android/app/src/main/res

> 2. rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* && rm -rf
>    android/app/src/main/res/raw/*
>
> Do I always have to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need clean with `./gradlew clean` then `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: I did but no luck.

Comment: gradlew clean is success or failed ?

Comment: gradlew clean is success.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the React Native Gradle Plugin, then you have to run this bundling command before every release build. The bundling command create a React Native bundle, which will be included with your native Android app. You can refer this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d)

If you don't want to run bundling command each time you make new build.

Comment: This solution is little but outdated and didn't solve . can you suggest other solution please.Many Thanks.